# Login with Facebook in wifi hotspot

Tags: oauth, wifi, facebook-oauth

we're developing a wifi hotspot captive portal where users can authenticate with their preferred social network credentials.

Of course before user's login on captive portal he/she can't reach internet, so some urls must be open in order to be able to reach external authentication pages.

Unfortunately for us, facebook's oauth dialog is "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth". Being https we can only open IPs or hostnames, but we have no control on "path" of the request, so we should open all www.facebook.com site. Unfortunately, for legal problems, it's not possible.

The simplest solution would be to have oauth dialog page on a different url (example: http://oauth.facebook.com/dialog/oauth...), is it possible?

Any other suggestion?

I've found some similar questions in this forum (so forgive me for the duplicate question), but none has an answer.

Comment: Nope, you can’t access Facebook endpoints under addresses of your own liking, just because the given ones don’t fit into your concept.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe, i understand this point. I was simply hoping, being this a common issue for wifi hotspots, that someone could help me in some way. Unfortunately, if i can't find a solution to this problem we must drop facebook login implementation for the moment :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sign in with Facebook oauth, without full facebook.com access](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8995467/sign-in-with-facebook-oauth-without-full-facebook-com-access)